# LDAP Search Filters using BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, ldap

I'm attempting to run the following query in a bash script, allowing me to check two different object classes for a defined attribute passed from a while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

inputfile="$1"
binddn="cn=admin,o=services"
password="BLAH"
IFS=','
while read -r Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5 Field6 ;
do
    ldapsearch -h "`hostname --fqdn`" -p 389 -x -LLL -D "${binddn}" -w "${password}" "'(&(|(ObjectClass=Group1)(ObjectClass=Group2))(Field1Attribute="${Field1}"))'"
done < "$inputfile"
exit 0
```

Any time I run the command, the variable Field1 passes successfully, but I get a bad search filter error:

```
ldapsearch -h HOSTNAME -p 389 -x -LLL -D cn=admin,o=services -w BLAH ''\''(&(|(ObjectClass=Group1)(ObjectClass=Group2))(Field1Attribute=FIELD1OUTPUT))'\'''
ldapsearch: ldap_search_ext: Bad search filter (87)
```

I noticed the command adds (''\') to the beginning and end to the filter.  I run the command manually minus the ticks and backslash, the query runs successfully.  How is this getting added in?

I've also passed both the search filter as a variable as well as the command itself without success.

Comment: Why do you have the single quotes in  `"'(&(|(ObjectClass...="${Field1}"))'"` ? I don't think `ldapsearch` expects them.

Comment: The single quotes are required.  Otherwise it will complain about the parentheses.  You need the parentheses in order to run a boolean filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do:

```
ldapsearch -h ... "'(&(this)(that="${Field1}"))'"
```

The single quotes will be part of of the quoted string, and they will go to `ldapsearch`. Which doesn't expect them, giving the error. Also, the expansion of `${Field1}` is unquoted, since the second double-quote ends the quoting. (Quotes don't nest.)

Your other output looks like the output of Bash's xtrace. It tries to tell you that the argument actually contains a literal quote, but the quoting is rather hard to read.

In this:

```
''\''(&(|(ObjectClass=Group1)(ObjectClass=Group2))(Field1Attribute=FIELD1OUTPUT))'\'''
```

we have

```
''           -- an empty string
\'           -- a literal backslash
'(&(|(...))' -- a quoted string
\'           -- another literal backslash
''           -- another empty string
```

I suspect what you want is either

```
ldapsearch -h ... "(&(this)(that=\"${Field1}\"))"
```

with the double quotes in the string going to `ldapsearch`, or

```
ldapsearch -h ... "(&(this)(that=${Field1}))"
```

without them.

In any case, without the surrounding single quotes. I'm not exactly sure if the double quotes should be there, I can't remember what format `ldapsearch` rules accept.

As far as I can test in practice, this works fine on one machine:

```
$ user=itvirta
$ ldapsearch -xLLL "(&(objectClass=shadowAccount)(uid=$user))" 
$ ldapsearch -xLLL '(&(objectClass=shadowAccount)(uid=itvirta))'
```

Comment: That was the trick.  Use the double quotes instead of the single quotes passed the command correctly in the script.  Thank you!